# Is an update in Cassandra not an anti pattern?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

As per Datastax documentation a read before a write in Cassandra is an anti pattern.

Whenever we use UPDATE either in CQLSH or using the Datastax drivers to set a few columns (with IFs & collection updates), does it not do a read before write first? Is that not an anti pattern? Am I missing something?

P.S I am not talking about mere UPSERTS but UPDATES on specific columns.

TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, Update is not an anti-pattern.**

In Cassandra update is an upsert operation similar to insert.

> UPDATE writes one or more column values to a row in a Cassandra table. Like INSERT, UPDATE is an upsert operation: if the specified row does not exist, the command creates it. All UPDATEs within the same partition key are applied atomically and in isolation.

But [Lightweight transactions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html#concept_ds_cfb_mcf_cl) are read before write operation. Actually at the cost of four round trips.

Example of Lightweight transaction :

```
#Lightweight transaction Insert
INSERT INTO customer_account (customerID, customer_email) 
VALUES (‘LauraS’, ‘lauras@gmail.com’)
IF NOT EXISTS;

#Lightweight transaction Update
UPDATE customer_account
SET    customer_email=’laurass@gmail.com’
IF     customerID=’LauraS’;
```

Both of the above statement are Lightweight transactions

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html#cqlUpdate__description

Comment: If light weight transactions are read before write does that not make it an anti pattern?

Comment: Also what about updates with setting of a few fields keeping the older values of the other columns intact? Will it not achieve that by doing a read first?

Comment: Yes, Lightweight transactions is anti-pattern, but if you need data consistency there is no other way.

Comment: Setting only few column will insert only these column.No read before write. When you execute read operation it will read each column with the latest value.

Comment: What about appending values to a collection like a map or a set?

Comment: Appending value in collection is also just upsert operation (because of internal structure) no read before write. But If you set value of collection (no append) it will first execute a delete operation and then insert

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know during a read the latest value of each column is looked up in case of specific column updates. I thought the entire latest row is fetched!

Comment: Read this to learn more about internal structure  http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/

Comment: Read and Write path of cassandra https://image.slidesharecdn.com/icde2014-cassandra-140526110404-phpapp02/95/cassandra-an-ssd-boosted-keyvalue-store-14-638.jpg?cb=1416412302